# Message of error each time I open Appcenter

Tags: updates, appcenter, release-hera, ppa, repositories

Every time I open the appcenter there is a message of "Failed to fetch updates" Everything seems to be working fine, but I would like to solve it

[image]

Here is the full content of the window

> W: Ignoring file 'brave-hera.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
>   E: Release file for http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 7h 57min 2s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
>   E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 9min 2s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
>   E: Release file for http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 17min 26s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
>   E: Release file for http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 11min 15s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
>   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
>   W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>   E: Release file for http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 7h 26min 49s). Updates for this repository will not be applied

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Is the time and date set correctly on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You might have broken packages.
Try the following it terminal 
you might need to install aptitude with
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I ran aptitude, but the problem still persists, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

AppCenter is attempting to check for Operating Software Updates.

The solution is to update/correct the source lists included with the distribution.

Replace all instances of "hera" with "bionic" (in 5.1 Hera) in the following 4 files:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
```

Once I made these changes, AppCenter was able to apply about 30+ updates and the dialog box has not reappeared.

I would recommend doing this right away as at least one of the updates is a security update.

A bug has been filed in GitHub ([os#316](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/316))