# Updating Hera: Expected bionic but got trusty

Tags: appcenter, release-hera, apt

When I check for updates on AppCenter, I get an error message "failed to fetch updates" 
W: Conflicting distribution: http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease (expected bionic but got trusty)

I had previously had similar problems to: [Message of error each time I open Appcenter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/message-of-error-each-time-i-open-appcenter)
but fixed those as per the recommendation.

Using Terminal - sudo apt-get update, I get various errors from deadsnakes, but also:

===========================

Reading package lists... Done
W: Conflicting distribution: http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease (expected bionic but got trusty)
W: Conflicting distribution: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease (expected bionic but got trusty)
W: Conflicting distribution: http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu bionic InRelease (expected bionic but got trusty)
N: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '14.04' to '18.04'
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'trusty-security' to 'bionic-security'
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'trusty' to 'bionic'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.

Any suggestions gratefully received.
Andy

Answer (score 0):

## 1. backup your sources.list

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`

## 2. change repos to bionic

`sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `trusty` with `bionic`. Probably some source lines are not the same for trusty and bionic so if you  still have errors for them you better remove these repositories from your sources list, the safest way is by putting a `#` in front of each line.